# X does not start after cygwin upgrade

Tags: cygwin

After upgrading Cygwin the X Server does not start. As far as I can tell the only error message from the command output is:

> xinit: XFree86_VT property unexpectedly has 0 items instead of 1

`/var/log/xwin/XWin.0.log` does not have this message.  I have pasted the entire output is at the bottom.

After initally installing from a cygwin mirror, I had used [Cygwin Ports](https://sourceware.org/cygwinports) to get a recent version of `git`. My latest update was from Cygwin mirror. Could that have caused the problem?

I have already tried reinstalling everything from cygwin mirror, using the reinstall option for every category. Do I have any other option besides uninstalling everything and reinstalling?

```
$ /usr/bin/startxwin

Welcome to the XWin X Server
Vendor: The Cygwin/X Project
Release: 1.16.2.0
OS: CYGWIN_NT-6.1 OAKN00563024A 1.7.33-2(0.280/5/3) 2014-11-13 15:47 x86_64
OS: Windows 7 Service Pack 1 [Windows NT 6.1 build 7601] (Win64)
Package: version 1.16.2-1 built 2014-11-11

XWin was started with the following command line:

/usr/bin/XWin :0 -multiwindow -nolisten tcp -auth
 /home/I063510/.serverauth.1328

(II) xorg.conf is not supported
(II) See http://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html for more information
LoadPreferences: /home/I063510/.XWinrc not found
LoadPreferences: Loading /etc/X11/system.XWinrc
LoadPreferences: Done parsing the configuration file...
winDetectSupportedEngines - DirectDraw4 installed, allowing ShadowDDNL
winDetectSupportedEngines - Returning, supported engines 00000015
winSetEngine - Multi Window or Rootless => ShadowGDI
winScreenInit - Using Windows display depth of 32 bits per pixel
winAllocateFBShadowGDI - Creating DIB with width: 1600 height: 900 depth: 32
winFinishScreenInitFB - Masks: 00ff0000 0000ff00 000000ff
winInitVisualsShadowGDI - Masks 00ff0000 0000ff00 000000ff BPRGB 8 d 24 bpp 32
MIT-SHM extension disabled due to lack of kernel support
XFree86-Bigfont extension local-client optimization disabled due to lack of shared memory support in the kernel
glWinSelectGLimplementation: Loaded 'cygnativeGLthunk.dll'
GL_VERSION:     4.3.0
GL_VENDOR:      NVIDIA Corporation
GL_RENDERER:    Quadro K2100M/PCIe/SSE2
(II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_SGI_make_current_read
(II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer
(II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_SGI_swap_control and GLX_MESA_swap_control
(II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_SGIX_pbuffer
(II) AIGLX: enabled GLX_ARB_multisample and GLX_SGIS_multisample
(II) 1002 pixel formats reported by wglGetPixelFormatAttribivARB
(II) AIGLX: Set GLX version to 1.4
(II) 825 fbConfigs
(II) ignored pixel formats: 0 not OpenGL, 54 RBGA float, 87 RGBA unsigned float, 0 unknown pixel type, 36 unaccelerated
(II) GLX: Initialized Win32 native WGL GL provider for screen 0
winPointerWarpCursor - Discarding first warp: 800 450
(--) 8 mouse buttons found
(--) Setting autorepeat to delay=500, rate=31
(--) Windows keyboard layout: "00000409" (00000409) "US", type 7
(--) Found matching XKB configuration "English (USA)"
(--) Model = "pc105" Layout = "us" Variant = "none" Options = "none"
Rules = "base" Model = "pc105" Layout = "us" Variant = "none" Options = "none"
winInitMultiWindowWM - DISPLAY=:0.0
winMultiWindowXMsgProc - DISPLAY=:0.0
winProcEstablishConnection - winInitClipboard returned.
winClipboardThreadProc - DISPLAY=:0.0
OS maintains clipboard viewer chain: yes
winMultiWindowXMsgProc - XOpenDisplay () returned and successfully opened the display.
winInitMultiWindowWM - XOpenDisplay () returned and successfully opened the display.
winClipboardProc - XOpenDisplay () returned and successfully opened the display.
xinit: XFree86_VT property unexpectedly has 0 items instead of 1
xinit: connection to X server lost

waiting for X server to shut down winClipboardProc - winClipboardFlushWindowsMessageQueue trapped WM_QUIT message, exiting main loop.
winClipboardProc - XDestroyWindow succeeded.
winClipboardIOErrorHandler!
winMultiWindowXMsgProcIOErrorHandler!
winInitMultiWindowXMsgProc - Caught IO Error.  Exiting.
winDeinitMultiWindowWM - Noting shutdown in progress
(EE) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I met the same problem after CygWin upgrade.

xwin works fine for me, and it's clean, without the ugly xterm window.

```
alias runx="run xwin -multiwindow -noclipboard"
```

According to Daniel, "-noclipboard" is not a must, Thanks.

Comment: This solved the problem for me and didn't open up an ugly xterm window like @Miserable Variable's answer did. For personal preference I used `-clipboard` rather than `-noclipboard`.

Comment: I too actually settled on this as the better solution :)

Comment: This worked like a dream for me. After months of looking for a solution. Added the alias to my `~/.profile`. Thanks

Comment: Works for me too. However, startxwin used to source my ~/.startxwinrc, which xwin doesn't (it sources ~/.XWinrc, which is not equivalent - it's not a shell script, but a resources file). Any idea how to get xwin to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks so much!! You save me a day!!

Answer (score 8):

I found the answer on [Cygwin-X mailing list](https://sourceware.org/ml/cygwin-xfree/2014-12/msg00011.html):

```
Once I switched to

xinit -- -multiwindow -clipboard &

I was fine.
```

Answer (score 6):

From http://x.cygwin.com/docs/ug/using.html:##

> - Note that startxwin no longer exits after ~/.startxwinrc has completed, leaving >X running, but, similar to startx, waits until ~/.startxwinrc exits and then kills X.
>
>   If you don't want the X server to exit until explicitly told to do so, end your ~/.startxwinrc with something like **exec sleep infinity**.

So, put at the end of your ~/.startxwinrc (if the file doesn't exist yet, create it):

```
exec sleep infinity
```

Answer (score 1):

I had such a problem, but found that the shortcut for starting xwin had the target

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\run.exe /usr/bin/bash.exe -l -c /usr/bin/startxwin.exe
```

But changing this to

```
C:\cygwin64\bin\run.exe /usr/bin/bash.exe -l -c /usr/bin/startxwin
```

makes it work.